# DomainRouting in vNext(Asp.net 5)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to do this

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "siteA",
    domain: "www.aaa.com", //Domain
    template: "{siteId}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}", //Url with siteId
    defaults: new { siteId = "1", controller = "Product", action = "Details" }); //domain(www.aaa.com)  match siteId=1

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "siteB",
    domain: "www.bbb.com",
    template: "{siteId}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { siteId = "2", controller = "Product", action = "Details" }); //domain(www.bbb.com)  match siteId=2

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "siteC",
    domain: "www.ccc.com",   
    template: "{siteId}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { siteId = "3", controller = "Product", action = "Details" }); //domain(www.ccc.com)  match siteId=3
```

Can anybody tell me how to do it?

I hope you can give me some code.

I know there some method like this :  http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx

But i don't know how to do it in vNext.

Comment: Domain routing was not yet ported to the new framework. I did contact the owner and let him know

Answer (score 0):

Check http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2015/02/17/Domain-Routing-and-resolving-current-tenant-with-ASPNET-MVC-6-ASPNET-5.aspx - I've written a fresh version that supports the (beta of) MVC 6.